# AC source resistance problem while simulating transformer in LTSpice

Tags: voltage, transformer, resistance

I am trying to build a Voltage quadruple circuit. But as per my requirement ,the source I will be using has a resistance of 25 ohms.As the input signal to too small I need to use a transformer to boost up the signal. while simulating the circuit in LT spice , if I give 25 Ohm as series resistance of the source.. the circuit is not working and showing very negligible output voltage. Please suggest me how to solve this problem?
[image: Voltage quadruple circuit]

Comment: What do you need this circuit for? will you actually build it, or does it only need to work in simulation?

Comment: I have to build the Circuit and the source is a Vibration sensor producing about 0.15v(minimum),20 Hz,and the internal resistance of the Vibration sensor(transducer) is 25 Ohms and here I am using coupled inductors to step up the small signal so that the diodes can work.

Comment: Why do you have to use a transformer? What's wrong with an op-amp?

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me out with this. But I did not mention one thing.. this project is related to energy harvesting. I had thought about using amplifiers to amplify the low voltage but the requirement of the project is I cannot use any kind of external voltage source(self powering),that is the reason I selected this circuit for my project.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to build it, I would discard this circuit. Spehro's answer shows you why.

I would just like to show you a circuit that could achieve what you need in a more practical way.

[image: Schematic]

You can see your sensor, the circuit is just an opamp inverting amplifier. You control the gain with the ratio R5/R2, 10 in this case. If you were to build the circuit, it would probably be a good idea to add 100nF in parallel with R4, and of course also in parallel with the supply of the opamp.

R3 and R4 form a voltage divider to add an offset of half the supply so that you dont clip the signal on the negative semiperiod, C1 is just ac coupling the input signal.

You can see a sample waveform below:

[image]

The blue trace is the input signal, the red one is the output signal. The output of the opamp is also very low impedance, so you could drive other stages/detectors with it.

One point to note is that C1 should be adjusted for the minimum frequency you are interested in. Right now, with this value, your bandwidth starts at around 2Hz as you can see in the following AC plot:

[image]

If you don't need such a low frequency, you can decrease the value of C1 proportionally.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me out with this. But I did not mention one thing.. this project is related to energy harvesting. I had thought about using amplifiers to amplify the low voltage but the requirement of the project is I cannot use any kind of external voltage source(self powering),that is the reason I selected this circuit for my project.

Comment: Oh, that makes it much more interesting...

Comment: Any alternative suggestion would be really helpful

Comment: What do you need, just a level detector?

Comment: Did you mean ac signal peak detector?

Comment: Yes, maybe if you give some details of what you expect as an output, it will be easier to propose a solution.

Comment: peak detector consist of diode.. and here my input is so small that a diode cannot work in that small voltage range. so I need to boost up the voltage and then use rectifier/peak detector.

Comment: output needed is regulated DC voltage (3.3v)

Comment: Will it be solved if  impedance matching  circuit is used or somehow impedance matching is done?

Answer (score 0):

Your transformer is not appropriate for a 20Hz signal- perhaps it would be for 20 MHz.

Try a design with a primary inductance that gives a reactance at your operating frequency that is at least 10x the 25 ohm source impedance. That's about 20H, so a lot of turns of wire on a fairly large core.

A more practical suggestion would be an AC coupled amplifier, which will be quite inexpensive and small.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in trying to help me out with this. But I did not mention one thing.. this project is related to energy harvesting. I had thought about using amplifiers to amplify the low voltage but the requirement of the project is I cannot use any kind of external voltage source(self powering),that is the reason I selected this circuit for my project.... It would be a help if I get any alternative suggestion on this.

Comment: You not only did not mention it, but were rather misleading by using the term "sensor". Conceptually you might be able to chop the input with an active circuit to use a smaller transformer or other inductive part but the circuit would not likely be self-starting. Otherwise you're stuck with a big transformer at 20Hz.

Comment: Will it be solved if  impedance matching  circuit is used or somehow impedance matching is done?

Comment: You mean, like a transformer? Yes. Try an 240:15 VAC transformer designed for mains frequency.

Comment: Can diodes with 400 mv forward voltage can be used?